# Setting local notification for a future date for Eastern time zone

Tags: iphone, ios, objective-c, xcode, apple-push-notifications

I'm working on adding local notifications to an app I'm developing. I'm setting just one notification for 11:00pm on April 30, 2013 NY/Eastern time. How would I do this? I've tried multiple methods but none of them have worked correctly. This is what I'm using at the moment (it doesn't work):

```
- (void)applicationDidEnterBackground:(UIApplication *)application
{
if (![@"1" isEqualToString:[[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults]
                            objectForKey:@"setNotify"]]) {
    [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] setValue:@"1" forKey:@"setNotify"];
    [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] synchronize];
    NSString *str = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"2013-04-23T18:22:00"];
    NSDateFormatter *dateFormat = [[NSDateFormatter alloc] init];
    [dateFormat setDateFormat:@"YYYY-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss'"];
    [dateFormat setTimeZone:[NSTimeZone timeZoneWithName:@"US/Eastern"]];
    NSDate *dte = [dateFormat dateFromString:str];
    NSCalendar *cal = [[NSCalendar alloc] initWithCalendarIdentifier:NSGregorianCalendar];
    [cal setTimeZone:[NSTimeZone timeZoneWithName:@"US/Eastern"]];
    UIApplication* app = [UIApplication sharedApplication];
    UILocalNotification* notifyAlarm = [[UILocalNotification alloc]
                                        init];
    if (notifyAlarm)
    {
        notifyAlarm.fireDate = dte;
        notifyAlarm.timeZone = [NSTimeZone timeZoneWithName:@"US/Eastern"];
        notifyAlarm.repeatInterval = 0;
        notifyAlarm.soundName = @"trumpet.m4a";
        notifyAlarm.alertBody = @"Message";
        [app scheduleLocalNotification:notifyAlarm];
    }
}
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Try the following code:

```
NSDateComponents *dateComps = [[NSDateComponents alloc] init];
[dateComps setDay:30];
[dateComps setMonth:4];
[dateComps setYear:2013];
[dateComps setHour:23];
[dateComps setMinute:0];
[dateComps setSecond:0];

NSDate *itemDate = [calendar dateFromComponents:dateComps];

UILocalNotification *localNotif = [[UILocalNotification alloc] init];
if (localNotif == nil)
    return;
localNotif.fireDate = itemDate;
localNotif.timeZone = [NSTimeZone timeZoneWithName:@"US/Eastern"];

localNotif.alertBody = @"Message";
localNotif.repeatInterval = 0;
localNotif.soundName = @"trumpet.m4a";
localNotif.applicationIconBadgeNumber = 1;

[[UIApplication sharedApplication] scheduleLocalNotification:localNotif];
```

Answer (score 1):

One thing I notice is that I doubt you meant to use YYYY in your date formatter.  From Apple Docs

```
A common mistake is to use YYYY. yyyy specifies the calendar year whereas
YYYY specifies the year (of “Week of Year”), used in the ISO year-week calendar.
In most cases, yyyy and YYYY yield the same number, however they may
be different. Typically you should use the calendar year.
```

When I changed this your code worked for me and posted a notification.